# Cant open skype again after closing it

Tags: skype

i have skype installed but if i close the "main menu" it is still running in the background but i cant open it again. How can i open the window again?

Comment: what gui interface and ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Unity, Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: There is a new Skype beta. Works fine on ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skype does currently not play well on ubuntu. A work around in your current situation would be to kill all running skype instances e.g. `pkill skype` or `killall skype` and then launch skype again.

If you want to avoid this in the future, don't close skype, just minimize it.

As an alternative, you might want to try the skype wrapper as described [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/skype-wrapper-0-4-adds-unity-features-menu-avatars-and-extra-settings/). As far as I know, this wrapper should be able to handle your situation as well.

Comment: +1, and if it does not work, then `killall -9 skype`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html

Skype is not white-listed in Ubuntu 11.10 but you can change this..

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386` and then restart your computer. You will have an icon of skype in the top bar of Ubuntu, where you can reopen it and also you can see the amount the unread messages!